# How to do syntax highlighting for a keyword containing a period (.)?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I tried the below to no avail.

```
syn keyword myConstant foo.bar "foo.bar" foo\.bar
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: `:help :syn-keyword` links to `:help :syn-iskeyword`.

Comment: How to do what you want is explained in the provided help sections, which you are supposed to *read* if you ever hope of writing a syntax script.

Comment: How am I supposed to know a period is covered in "iskeyword" ?There are 5500 lines to read in the file. Even if I read the whole thing several times before, chances are pretty large I'd have forgotten.

Comment: 1. `iskeyword` is mentioned very early in the user manual (chapter 3), the  reading of which is required for anyone planning to make Vim their main editor. It's a basic. 2. You are using `syntax keyword ...` so the very least you should do is read `:help :syn-keyword`—you know… to understand how it works instead of typing text randomly—which says "Don't forget that a keyword can only be recognized if all the characters are included in the 'iskeyword' option. If one character isn't, the keyword will never be recognized." and links to `:help 'iskeyword'` and `:help :syn-iskeyword`. Try harder.

Comment: Funny how I've used vim for 20 years and never needed to know about iskeyword before.

Comment: Well that's one of the cool things about Vim: the learning never stops.

Answer (score 2):

There is a string what identifies what are valid characters in a keyword. The string is called `iskeyword` (which sounds like a bool).

The default string as of this writing is `@,48-57,192-255,$,_`

The solution was to modify the iskeyword string to include the period which I appended at the end. The final result is:  `syntax iskeyword @,48-57,192-255,$,_,.`

Comment: I think the right place to change iskeyword is on: `/.vim/after/ftplugin/filetype.vim where filetype would be php.vim or something like that: and instead of set use setlocal, so it will only change the given filetype.